# How many integers between 1 and 1000 inclusive have a sum of digits equal to 10?

Tags: combinatorics

What would be the approach to solve the question ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Write down some numbers that sum up to ten and look for a pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mainly use "stars and bars":

A sequence of 10 stars and 2 bars can be interpreted as three non-negative numbers that sum to 10. There are $10+2\choose 2$ such sequences. However, three of these sequences would require a digit 10 and have to be subtracted.
So
$${12\choose 2}-3=66-3=63. $$

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of computer help gave $63$ as the solution.

The approach would be "computer help" . Maybe you had something else in mind, but this would be one way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**The "roll sleeves" approach, also known as "brute force":**

$$
19,28,37,46,55,64,73,82,91,\\
109,118,127,136,145,154,163,172,181,190,\\
208,217,226,235,244,253,262,271,280,\\
307,316,325,334,343,352,361,370,\\
406,415,424,433,442,451,460,\\
505,514,523,532,541,550,\\
604,613,622,631,640,\\
703,712,721,730,\\
802,811,820,\\
901,910.\\
$$